# Make directory executable in terminal

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-ec2, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm trying to install my cloud code from my old parse server onto my new ec2 instance server using Parse's server api.  Everything works great but im hung up on one side note: changing the server instance's code through amazons eb cli.  The very last part instructs me make my cloud directory to what i believe is an executable like so

[image]

How do I do this in the terminal?  i tried renaming it but its the same name so that wont work.  Is it a permissions change?

Heres the link to the git tutorial containing those instructions:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I believe what that document is telling you is to replace any paths *inside your code* to be dot-leading relative paths.  So if you had:

```
var name = require('cloud/name.js');
```

You would need to change it to

```
var name = require('./cloud/name.js');
```

PS: while I don't believe you need to change a directory to be executable, should you need do to that, the syntax is:

```
chmod +x directoryname
```

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: How did you end up solving this?